# Get random data from other excel files while retaining color

Tags: excel

For example:
I have 2 file excel with name is Excel1.xlsx and Excel2.xlsx

In Sheet 1 Excel1.xlsx i have:

B1 with text is: b1 anh fill color: red

C1 with text is: c1 anh fill color: blue

D1 with text is: d1 anh fill color: green

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZP0P.jpg)

Now i want go to file Excle2.xlsx and get data random from Excel1.xlsx which retaining color

Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you just  copying from excel 1 to Excel 2 ? If so then why cant you just pre set up the colours in Excel 2? Using conditional formatting

Comment: can u help me aboy Conditional formatting ? Kyoujin
about VBA, show for me, pls !! pnuts